# How would a "register volatile int i" behave in C?

Tags: c, volatile

I understand that a register keyword will assign a register for computing the value and a volatile keyword will read the value from the memory every time when we perform some computation on the variable and basically not optimize the code. So, if a variable is assigned both these keywords then, would it mean that it would essentially be volatile itself? I cannot understand the behavior by writing a sample code. Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: What platform and compiler? I don't think most general compilers (such as GCC in default configuration) will respect `register`.

Comment: The one effect that `register` must have is that you can't take the address of a variable declared such.

Comment: @Daniel : I did not understand your point.. Cant take address of the variable as in? DO you mean to say that it can be accessed by a pointer?

Comment: If a variable is declared as `register int some_var;` (or `register volatile int some_var;`), having `&some_var` in the source code is a constraint violation and requires a diagnostic (whether the compiler aborts compilation or not is up to the compiler, but your programme is not conforming).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C, the `register` storage class behaves exactly as the `auto` storage class, except that the implementation is required (per 5.1.1.3) to issue a diagnostic if the program attempts to take or use the address of the object (6.5.3.2, 6.7.1).  The use of `register` as an optimisation hint to the compiler is generally pointless, as a compiler smart enough to exploit the non-stored quality of the object is certainly smart enough to track which objects could be declared `register`; instead, it should be understood as a code quality check that the programmer is not inadvertently destroying optimisation opportunities by taking the address of the object.

In other words, removing all instances of the `register` keyword from a valid program has *no effect* on the program's semantics; it is similar in this regard to `static_assert`.

The `volatile` type qualifier indicates that accesses to (reads from and writes to) the object are considered side effects and cannot be optimised away.  For an object that does not exist in a defined location memory (i.e., one having the `register` storage class), this would be most useful in performance testing:

```
start = time();
for (multiple loops)
    register volatile int result = test_function();
stop = time();
elapsed = stop - start;
```

Comment: I'm curious how's `register volatile` in your example differs from simply `volatile`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight there is no difference, because the program is valid.

Comment: A more understandable view of volatile keyword is that it tells the compiler that whenever the variable is specified, the compiler should assume that the variable may have been changed by some other process or thread or device.  Compilers when optimizing may eliminate accessing a variable repeatedly by assuming that if the variable value is loaded into a register, the value in the register can be depended on as a current copy of the value until such time the compiler finds source code that modifies the variable.  Volatile tells the compiler that this assumption is not valid.

Comment: Actually register has one trait that an `auto` variable doesn't: You **cannot** take the address of a register variable.

Comment: @RichardChambers right, but that doesn't make sense for a `register` object, which does not have a defined location in memory.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII that's what I said above. So removing `register` from a valid program will not alter its semantics.

Comment: @ecatmur : So I understand that "register volatile int i" will generically behave as a "volatile int i" ?

Comment: @RichardChambers: If the address of the volatile object is not taken and it has automatic storage duration, there is fundamentally no way another thread/device/etc. could modify the object. One might argue that a debugger counts, however. Otherwise, I think by the "as-if rule" a C implementation is probably free to fully optimize away such volatile objects, being as there is no way to observe their existence.

Answer (score 6):

`volatile` means that the object may change in a way that is unpredictable to the compiler and `register` means that its address can't be taken.

The combination of both makes perfect sense, when the object is in fact a hardware register on the platform. Some compilers (e.g gcc) even have extensions to fix such a variable to a specific hardware register.

Some other code might change such a hardware register, and so the compiler may assume nothing about the current value. In such a case it would even make sense to add a `const` qualifier. E.g with gcc's extension

```
register uint32_t volatile const eax __asm__("eax");
```

you'd have a tool to inspect the `eax` register at any moment, but you wouldn't be able to change it by accident.

Comment: `volatile` also means that all writes to the variable must actually happen.

Comment: @TorKlingberg, what do you mean by a "write" to a `register` variable. There is no model of "storage" for such a variable, and so no model of "read" or "write".

Comment: @JensGustedt: In a function which uses `setjmp`, I think an object with both `volatile` and `register` qualifiers would be required to reflect any changes made to its value between the two returns from `setjmp`, while one that was merely qualified `register` would not.